# Prove that the functional is non-negative for $x_i\geq 0$

Tags: inequality

Consider the following functional $\Phi:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R $:
$$
\Phi(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(1+x_i)(x_i-x_n)^2(2(1+x_i+x_n)+x_i x_n-x_1).
$$
The computer experiments show that it is non-negative for all $x_i\geq 0$. I need to prove this. Note that we have both $\Phi(x)=0$ and $\nabla \Phi(x)=0$ for all $x$ with equal coordinates. The proof should be simple, but I can't manage to find it. Any ideas?

Comment: $\Phi$ is not nonnegative on $\mathbb R^n$. E.g. when $x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_{n-1}=1$, $\Phi(x)=6(n-1)(x_n-1)^2(x_n+1)$, which is negative when $x_n+1<0$.

Comment: @user1551 thank you very much, you are right. I corrected the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Phi$ is not always nonnegative. Let $f(x_i)=(1+x_i)(x_i-x_n)^2(2(1+x_i+x_n)+x_i x_n-x_1)$. When $x_1=7,\,x_2=x_3=\cdots=x_{n-1}=1$ and $x_n=0$, we have, for $2\le i\le n-1$,
\begin{aligned}
f(x_i)
&=(1+x_i)(x_i-x_n)^2(2(1+x_i+x_n)+x_i x_n-x_1)\\
&=2(1)^2\left(2(1+1+0)+0-7\right)\\
&=-6.
\end{aligned}
Therefore $\Phi(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f(x_i)=f(x_1)-6(n-2)$ is negative when $n$ is sufficiently large.

Comment: Could you please take a look at a similar inequality? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3075042/633591

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, merely recording a partial result, found trying to find the least $n$ with a $\Phi_n(x) < 0$.

\begin{align*}
\Phi_{78}(\frac{13018}{3}, 1626, \dots, 1626,0)  = \frac{-868\,706\,947\,328}{81}
\end{align*}
In fact, $\Phi_{78}\left( \frac{25979 b}{9736}, b, \dots, b, 0 \right)$ has constant negative fourth derivative and has negative first, second, and third derivatives as soon as $b > 1200.487\dots$, so $\Phi_{78}$ decreases like $\Theta(-b^4)$ starting there.  ([More](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations) on $\Theta$.)